# How to parse Brazil (Portugal) date?

Tags: java, date, datetime, locale, datetime-parsing

In java there aren't Brazil locale for parsing date

I need parse this date - 11 de Ago de 2020 09:04

I create

```
BrazilLocale = Locale.Builder().setLanguage("pt").setRegion("BR").build()
```

and this pattern `dd MMM yyyy hh:mm` but it doesn't work.

For example we can try:

```
    Locale brazilLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("pt").setRegion("BR").build();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm", brazilLocale);
    String stringToParse = "11 de Ago de 2020 09:04";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringToParse, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Expected output: `2020-08-11T09:04`.

Observed output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text '11 de Ago de 2020 09:04' could not be parsed at index 3

The exception happens in this line:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringToParse, formatter);
```

When I tried with the old-fashioned `SimpleDateFormat` instead, I got

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "11 de Ago de 2020 09:04"

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context. How are you using that pattern? can you provide a bit more of your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Correction: Java includes a Brazilian Portuguese locale, your locale variable works. Maybe your problem is that your string is using the wrong case. At least on my Java 11 that locale expects “ago” in all lower case unless I instruct my `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to use use case insensitive parsing. We can help you better if you provide the code that is failing for you. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As you have observed, questions without a minimal reproducible code example and expected and observed result tend to get closed quickly here on Stack Overflow. I have edited your question to show one way it can be done. Whether we can have your question reopened depends on three users with sufficient reputation noticing the edit and voting to reopen. I can’t tell whether that will happen now, 19 hours after the question was asked and in the weekend, where fewer users visit. We’ll see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your problems is the 'de' that in Portuguese makes de relation between the days/month and year. Java will not understand that so you have to 'hard code' that in your pattern. `hh` means 'clock-hour-of-am-pm' but you are not specifying 'am' or 'pm', so you should use `HH` most likely. Here is a working example:

```
Locale brazilLocale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
           .parseCaseInsensitive()
           .appendPattern("dd 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy HH:mm")
           .toFormatter(brazilLocale);
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("11 de ago de 2020 09:04", formatted));
```

Resulting in `2020-08-11T09:04`